# How to get UITextField cursor change event?

Tags: ios, events, uitextfield, text-cursor

I'm working on Android TV Remote Controller - iOS version

I need to detect cursor change event in UITextField and send this event to Android TV.

I can't find any Delegate or notification will send UITextfield cursor change event.

Is there any way to get this event?

Many thanks.

Comment: The problem is still unsolved. But I have a work around solution. The way is monitoring content of TextField. You can compare with old content then you will know the change point. Move your cursor behind the point. The disadvantage is lacking of information if user only move cursor position but don't type anything.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you can KVO or subclass.
Since @NSLeader gave the answer for KVO, I'll explain the latter.

Here is a subclass example:

```
class MyUITextFieldThatEmitsCursorChangeEvents: UITextField
{
    //Override this, but don't prevent change to its default behavior by 
    //calling the super getter and setter.
    override var selectedTextRange: UITextRange? {
        get {return super.selectedTextRange}
        set {
            self.emitNewlySetCursor(event: newValue) //<- Intercept the value
            super.selectedTextRange = newValue       //Maintain normal behavior
        }
    }
    //I'm going to use a closure to pass the cursor position out, 
    //but you can use a protocol, NotificationCenter, or whatever floats your
    //boat.
    weak var cursorPosnDidChangeEvent: ((Int) -> ())?
    
    //I'm going to abstract the logic here to keep the previous code slim.
    private func emitNewlySetCursor(event range: UITextRange?)
    {
        //Now you have access to the start and end in range.
        //If .start and .end are different, then it means text is highlighted.
        //If you only care about the position where text is about to be 
        //entered, then only worry about .start.
        //This is an example to calculate the cursor position.
        if let rawRangeComponent = range?.start 
        {
            let cursorPosition = offset(from: beginningOfDocument, 
                                        to: rawRangeComponent)

            //Emit the value to whoever cares about it
            self.cursorPosnDidChangeEvent?(cursorPosition) 
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for example, if we're in a UIViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let tf = MyUITextFieldThatEmitsCursorChangeEvents(frame: .zero)
    self.view.addSubview(tf)
    tf.cursorPosnDidChangeEvent = { newCursorPosn in
        print(newCursorPosn) //( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
    }
}
```

Comment: you are Perfect :))

Answer (score 0):

Observe `selectedTextRange` property.

Example on RxSwift:

```
textField.rx.observeWeakly(UITextRange.self, "selectedTextRange")
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)
            .skip(1)
            .bind { (newTextRange) in
                print(newTextRange)
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Using `RxSwift` to explain makes it difficult to understand how `UIKit` can be customized to answer the question.